# How do I change a css style if value is greater than 1 using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the style of a span if the contents of the span is greater than 1. I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

if ($(".over").length > 0) {
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(this).css("color", "red");

} 
else {
    $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
}

});
```

The number is 0 to 1 in the span tag. If the number within the span is greater than 1 I would like to change the content of the span (number) to bold and make it red. Not sure if length or value will do the trick

Comment: if there is no content in the span why you need a font? Also is `.over` your span?

Comment: You mean "not empty"?

Comment: `$(".over").length` will count the number of elements that have the class `over`.

Comment: Ok, the number is 0 to 1 in the span tag. If the number within the span is greater than 1 I would like to change the content of the span (number) to bold and make it red

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should accomplish what you want:

HTML:

```
<span class="over">0</span>
<span class="over">1</span>
<span class="over">2</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".over").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var value = parseFloat(el.text());
        if (value > 1) {
            el
                .css("font-weight", "bold")
                .css("color", "red");

        } else {
            el.css("font-weight", "normal");
        }
    });   

});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmesE/1/

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm

Comment: Why does this not work as soon as I change <span class... to <td class? I'd like to use this in my table.